# Dynamically add values to SELECT box, appended to body

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to append values to a SELECT box, that gets dynamically added to the `body` of a page. A fiddle can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/mr2qtmw9/

HTML:

```
<body>

foo bar

</body>
```

JS:

```
var countries = new Object();
countries['AT'] = "Austria";
countries['AU'] = "Australia";
countries['BE'] = "Belgium";
countries['BG'] = "Bulgaria";
countries['CA'] = "Canada";

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('body').append( "<select id='foo'></select>" );

  // fill out the country, and its selected value
  $.each(countries, function(i,x) {
    $('#Country').append($('<option>', { value : i }).text(x));
  });

});
```

The `SELECT` box gets created, and the $.each() runs through... but the option's don't get added.

What am I missing? (the same code works fine when the select box appears on the initial DOM... it just seems to have an issue when its dynamically injected)

**UPDATE:** Sorry, I put the wrong ID in the example! On the live script, the ID is "Country", and the selector is "#Country". It still doesn't work on my dev server (much more complex code), so I guess the issue must lie elsewhere :(

**UPDATE 2:** Doh, this was a big oversight on my part! (sometimes writing up and issue helps you to spot these). I put an `alert()` inside the function that was doing the work, and found it was running 2 times. Sure enough, after checking the code I found there was a 2nd place I was calling the same function. As such, it WAS adding the options, but to the 1st instance of the SELECT (and the 2nd one was overlapping, so I couldn't see the first one).

I have half a mind to delete this question, as it makes me look so dumb... but I think I'll leave it up, so hopefully it can help save someone else from a similar embarrassment ;)

Comment: Wrong id, that's all...

Comment: `$('#Country') !== $('#foo')`

Comment: Thanks guys - that was a boo-boo my end. The actual code has them set correctly. The jsfiddle runs fine now, but my script doesn't (on the server). I'll keep digging

Comment: @AndrewNewby, do you have errors in console ?

Comment: Both answer are correct...please approve any one so it will be helpfull to others

Comment: Ah man, I see it! I had show_update_settings() being run 2 times (once on init, and again somewhere else). Got rid of the 2nd one, and its good now (it was added the options, but to the 1st instance of the ID - duh!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the id `foo` on the select but you were using `Country` when appending the `option`. This should work:

```js
var countries = new Object();
countries['AT'] = "Austria";
countries['AU'] = "Australia";
countries['BE'] = "Belgium";
countries['BG'] = "Bulgaria";
countries['CA'] = "Canada";

$(document).ready(function() {

 $('body').append( "<select id='Country'></select>" );

  // fill out the country, and its selected value
  $.each(countries, function(i,x) {
    $('#Country').append($('<option>', { value : i }).text(x));
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

foo bar

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks - that was just me being silly on my jsfiddle. The weird thing, is that that DOES work, yet on my dev site it's not (the code is more complex there, which is why I simplified). Guess I need to did a bit deeper to see whats going on :(

Comment: I'm glad it worked somehow. But you should post another question maybe with another/more code. Maybe someone can help you. Maybe you forgot to include jQuery on your server.

Comment: I'm going to accept this one, purely because it was posted 1 minute before the other answer. While it didn't actually "fix" the real issue I was having, it was correct with regards to my boo-boo in the JSFiddle ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just need to change id to foo when you append

```js
var countries = new Object();
countries['AT'] = "Austria";
countries['AU'] = "Australia";
countries['BE'] = "Belgium";
countries['BG'] = "Bulgaria";
countries['CA'] = "Canada";

$(document).ready(function() {

 $('body').append( "<select id='foo'></select>" );

  // fill out the country, and its selected value
  $.each(countries, function(i,x) {
    $('#foo').append($('<option>', { value : i }).text(x));
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

foo bar

</body>
```